# Setting .runsettings path per solution in Rider

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Is there a way to set the .runsettings path per solution? Right now it's a global setting and I have to change it when I switch solutions.

If not, is there a way to specify it as a relative path to a sln file? We have quite strict solution structure, so that would be helpful enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should utilize settings layers feature of IDE. Say, either personal or team-shared, depending on your needs. Right click on the required layer, then "Edit" and then set the runsettings file as usual. It should be saved to the corresponding solution-wise settings file.

[image]